# Domain Events with regards to Rollbak

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, domain-driven-design, domain-events

Working with `Domain Driven Design` with `Mongodb` and an external service. Let's say we have two services `Service A (for aggregate A)` and `Service B for aggregate B`. Whenever an `Aggregate A` is created, a corresponding `Aggregate B` is also created. This is done `synchronously via an API call` to ensure real-time operations. In case the creation of `Aggregate B` fails, the creation of `Aggregate A` needs to be rolled back.

The Domain Event `Aggregate_A_Created` is fired once the `Aggregate A` is stored in DB (handled via ORM). Before the `Aggregate B` is created.

The problem I face is quite simple, if the `Aggregate A` was created, the event is fired but if the `Aggregate B` creation fails, the `Aggregate A` is deleted from the database but the Domain Event was fired that already signifies that `Aggregate_A_Created`. This might lead the system into an invalid state where other services think that `Aggregate A` exists but in reality it fails.

I can fire another event `Aggregate_A_deleted` but what if a service receives the `Deleted` event before the `Created` event?

I am stuck here, some insights would be great. Can I change the Spring Implementation to fire the domain event only when both operations have succeeded? I read that Spring Mongodb doesn't support Transactional calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Aggregate A and Aggregate B cannot be separated, should they not be parts of a common aggregate root?

If they are really separate, B should listen to A being created and only acknowledge that event, if B creation succeeds. This way - provided that you have
persistent events - a B will be created even if the system goes down after A has been created and gets restored to that state.

Regarding transactions: as mongodb itself can handle transactions, don't let your choice of libraries limit you. If spring cannot do it, use the driver directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does shed some insights on the potential solution. Would you be able to share some more information on Common Aggregate Root? Is there a link I can follow? The reason why I've made the `Aggregate A`  -> `Aggregate B` as synchronous is because as long as `Aggregate B` is not created, no one will be able to use `Aggregate A` and after creating the `Aggregate A` the expectation is to go right in and start using `Aggregate A` which under a larger queue size would fail since time to process the message would be high.

Comment: @iam.Carrot  No, not a link from the top of my head. However, if A has the absolute necessity that B must be present, there is a hard dependency. So either make B a member of A, or unify them under a common object C which has members A and B.

Comment: Great. Thanks to you it triggered a different thought process that actually lead me to a much more feasible solution maintaining an `async` communication method.